# The requested view 1.php could not be found in kohana

Tags: kohana, php

I'm trying to learn the framework kohana.
I have defined a new controller under application/controller/classes. Which I named to hello.php:

```
class Controller_Hello extends Controller
{

public function action_say(){
    $g = new View('firstv');
    $g->render(TRUE);

}

}
?>
```

And I have this under application/views. Which I called firstv.php:

```
<h1>testing1</h1>
```

What's the mistake here. I'm using this guide:
http://pixelpeter.com/kohana/kohana101.pdf

I'm using the latest stable version 3.1.3.1. I have called the function by navigating to:
http://localhost/kohana/index.php/hello/say

Tried this using the same say function. And it worked. But this one doesn't use views.

```
$this->response->body('hello, world 2!');
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Please take a screenshot with error stack showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->response->body($g->render());
```

So your complete action method will be something like:

```
public function action_say()
{
    $g = new View('firstv');
    $this->response->body($g->render());
}
```

or:

```
public function action_say()
{
    $g = new View('firstv');
    $this->response->body($g);
}
```

or even:

```
public function action_say()
{
    $this->response->body(new View('firstv'));
}
```